# Query shortest path with conditions on Orient-db

Tags: java, orientdb, orientdb2.2

We are working with OrientDB (V 2.2.30) and using ‘*shortestPath*’ function.

We want to get the shortest path between 2 vertices but only a path that applies to a condition on a specific field such as "Status=Active". 
i.e. if one of the items within the shortest path doesn't match to the condition "Status=Active", the whole path will not come as an output and we will get the "next" shortest path that matches to the condition.
We saw in the Orient documentation that there is an *additionalParams* parameter,
But the only parameter Currently allowed is 'maxDepth'.

Is there any way we can get the shortest path with conditions?

Comment: Will something like this work?   SELECT expand(path) FROM (
  SELECT shortestPath($from, $to) AS path 
  LET 
    $from = (SELECT FROM Profiles WHERE Name='Santo' and Surname='OrientDB'), 
    $to = (SELECT FROM Countries WHERE Name='United States') 
  UNWIND path
)

Comment: No, because this query doesn't check the vertices in the path, it checks just the from and to vertices. thanks anyway

Comment: Hi, do you prefer a SQL query or a JS function, that you can call by SQL command, is fine as well? Thx

Comment: Hey, I prefer a SQL query, but if you have a solution for the second option, ill be happy to hear.